# Python adding \ when printing '

Tags: python

In the interpreter, when I'm writing the code

```
"it's 42\""
```

To make python display

```
'it's 42"'
```

It's displaying

```
'it\'s 42"'
```

Instead. Now, I would like to understand why, more then getting around that.

Comment: Why not? If you don't escape your character, how does the program knows where your string ends if you start it with `'`

Comment: It doesn't. How are you "printing" that value?

Comment: There is a difference between printing and displaying.

Comment: When the interpreter get's a result it uses the `__repr__()` to display the result. Strings use `'` to delimit their representations so need to escape any `'` in the value. When you actually `print("it's 42\"")` it outputs `it's 42"`

Comment: @VincentSavard, the OP's not printing, the interpreter is displaying, which indeed it does if you type only "it's 42\"" into the interpreter `>>> "it's 42\""` outputs `'it\'s 42"'`

Comment: @downshift: Which is exactly why I asked that question, and placed "printing" between quotes.

Comment: OP stated "make python print" not he explicitly used "print" I guess it's a misinterpreting of semantics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type to the shell:

```
"it's 42\""
```

It displays the string variable created from what your wrote, and python **defaults to ' usage**. So you get:

```
'it\'s 42"'
```

which, when you think about it, is the exact same string you wrote! You used "" to denote the string and escaped the extra ", but python uses in the shell ' and escapes the extra one in the it **'** s.

To **show the string properly** use the **print** method which reads the escapes properly. I guarantee printing your version or the version your shell returns will both yield what you wanted.

On a side note you can use triple quotes to skip escapes all together:

```
'''it's 42"'''
```

The caveat is you can't use triple double quotes, because python will think the end of your string is part of the string enclosure.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `print("it's 42\"")`?  If you are just doing

```
>>>"it's 42\""
'it\'s 42"
```

Then you are not actually printing the string, just displaying its value.

Comment: Yeah, im displaying, not printing. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I thin it's because if you use **'** in string, for display it, python frame string with **"** :

```
>> "it's 42"
"it's 42"
```

Now if use **"** in string, python frame string with **'** :

```
>> "\"it s 42\""
'"it s 42"'
```

But if you use 2 in the same time python escape automatically one of two for not confuse with that frames the chain :

```
>> "it's 42\""
'it\'s 42"'
```

Comment: But then, what is / good for? I would think it's here to make python notice that the next char is not a " but the ascii value of" to display that char

Comment: yes, I think so too, for not confuse with 'reel' **'** framing printed string